# Unity 3D Vector calculating on one axis crossing other axis

Tags: math, unity-game-engine

Hey I have a problem and I do not get this calculated on Unity 3D

I want to manipulate vertices. Thats ok but I want to move on X Axis where my mouse is. That doesn't work properly.

So what I do is just throw a ray from origin to a direction. So the ray could be infinitiv long.

With this I want to move the vertice of the mesh to the point where the mouse is. I limited it the range with ray_z = vertice_z (pseudo) but if you look the black line which is the ray you notice it getting longer or shorter when I move or rotate the camera. So the vertice is not on the same position like the mouse.

So I don't get calculated. How can I calculate the position from Z (black line) crosses X (red line).

Example:

- cam(1,0,0) // cam & the start position of the ray
- x_axis(10,0,10) // red line cutting black
- ray_position(15,0,15) // the end of the ray (where the mouse could be if you look from cam to mouse)

Btw: The viewport is not top down. I painted wrong.

If you didn't understand I may try again ^^.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Plane.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html), I think.

Let's say your plane has a `<0, 0, -1>` normal (the x-y plane) and passes through the origin:

```
Plane p = new Plane(Vector3.back, Vector3.zero);
```

Then you can find the point where a camera/mouse ray intersects with that plane:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

float distanceAlongRay;
p.Raycast(ray, out distanceAlongRay);
Vector3 mouseOnPlane = ray.GetPoint(distanceAlongRay);
```

`mouseOnPlane` is the point on the x-y plane where the mouse ray hit. If you're only interested in the x, then use `mouseOnPlane.x`.

Comment: Woo thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. Didn't know Plane